# XSD Multiple elements with the same name but different attribute value

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to create an XML schema for the following:

```
        <SomeApp>
            <Org>Dataset</Org>
            <Name>Foo</Name>
            <Version>1.00</Version>
            <Source>25839</Source>
            <UniversalID>867-5309</UniversalID>
            <TestField Name="Price">7.00</TestField>
            <TestField Name="Level">5.00</TestField>
            <TestField Name="new">false</TestField>
            <TestField Name="Description">Bar</TestField>
        </SomeApp>
```

I'm OK until the parser reaches the `<TestField>` elements. I can handle *one* of these elements like so...

```
               <xs:element name="TestField" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                                <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
```

...but of course the parser doesn't allow the next element of the same name, and defining it again (with the simpleContent set to match the next data type) doesn't do the trick either. Here is one of the XSD formats I've tried, just to pass the first two TestField elements:

```
                <xs:complexType name="TestFieldType">
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                            <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:enumeration value="Price"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="Level"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>

                <xs:element name="TestField" type="TestFieldType"/>
```

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Where you have '<xs:element name="TestField" minOccurs="0">', just add maxOccurs="unbounded" alongside the minOccurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it out.

**XML**

```
<SomeApp>
    <Org>Dataset</Org>
    <Name>Foo</Name>
    <Version>1.00</Version>
    <Source>25839</Source>
    <UniversalID>867-5309</UniversalID>
    <TestField Name="Price">7.00</TestField>
    <TestField Name="Level">5.00</TestField>
    <TestField Name="Description">Bar</TestField>
</SomeApp>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="SomeApp">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Org"/>
                <xs:element ref="Name"/>
                <xs:element ref="Version"/>
                <xs:element ref="Source"/>
                <xs:element ref="UniversalID"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="TestField"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Org" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Version" type="xs:decimal"/>
    <xs:element name="Source" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="UniversalID" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="TestField">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="Name" use="required" type="TestFieldType"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="TestFieldType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Price"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Level"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Description"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a rule `ElementDeclarationsConsistent` which says that if two elements are siblings of each other and have the same name, then they must have the same type.

I'm not sure exactly what constraints you want to impose, but if for example you want to say that for any `TestField`, if the value of `@Name` is 'Price' then the value must be `xs:decimal`, then this needs XSD 1.1 assertions:

```
<xs:assert test="@Name ne 'Price' or string(.) castable as xs:decimal"/>
```

Similarly if you want to assert that the first TestField must have `@Name="Price"` then this needs an assertion on the `SomeApp` element:

```
<xs:assert test="TestField[1]/@Name = 'Price'"/>
```